# how to select Morris.js Donut chart section on resize

Tags: javascript, select, resize, morris.js

I have Donut chart with "resize': 'true' option and I custom select section chart.select(index) ,but after page resizing the selected section reset to the default one, how to prevent it? If I try to set Item value on resize manually,the labels inside donut and selected section blinks. How to make the chart does not blink and set appropriate selected item right after chart appears?

```
$(function () {
  window.m = Morris.Donut({
    element: 'container',
    resize: true,
    data: [
      {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
      {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
      {label: "Order Sales", value: 20},
      {label: "Mail Sales", value: 40}]
   });

    window.m.select(2);

     $(window).on('resize', function() {
       if (!window.recentResize) {
         window.m.redraw();
         window.recentResize = true;
         setTimeout(function(){ window.recentResize = false; window.m.select(2);}, 200);
       }
     });
});
```

How it awful works now, try to resize container http://jsfiddle.net/dkwtd16h/4/